# Steps to Move TFS 2010 to New Data Tier

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs

I'm planning to replace our current physical data tier with a shiny new virtual. SharePoint and the Tfs_Analysis databases will remain where they are, so I shouldn't need to  move/restore them(?). To me it seems like the transition should go something like this:

AT = App Tier and 
DT = Data Tier

1. On the AT Run: TFSServiceControl quiesce
2. On the AT Run: TFSConfig setup /uninstall:ApplictionTier
3. On the AT Stop: SSAS and SSRS services
4. On the new DT Restore:

   - ReportServer
   - ReportServerTempDB
   - Tfs_Configuration
   - Tfs_DefaultCollection
   - Tfs_ArchiveCollection
   - Tfs_Warehouse
5. On the new DT Update: Connection strings in the Tfs_Configuration.dbo.tbl_ServiceHost table to reflect the new DT.
6. On the AT Start: SSAS service
7. On the AT Update: Tfs_Analysis datasource connection string to reflect the new DT.
8. On the AT, remap DBs and restamp TFS:

   - TFSConfig Identities [...]
   - TFSConfig PrepSQL [...]
   - TFSConfig RemapDBs [...]
   - TFSConfig Accounts [...]
   - TFSConfig ChangeServerID [...]
9. On the AT Run: Admin Console and select the AT Only Wizard.
10. On the AT Run: TFSConfig registerDB [...]
11. On the AT Run: Reporting Services Configuration Manager to point to the new DT.
12. On the AT Run: Admin Console and redirect reporting to the new DT.
13. On the AT Run: TFSServiceControl unquiesce
14. Re-point data sources in Reports Manager
15. Smoke test

Do any of you guys see any flaws with this? Does it even make sense? :)

Comment: I would just follow whatever the Microsoft recommends: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mike mentioned in his comment, follow the guidance from the TFS Administration Guide. You'll specifically be doing a restoration of data to a new server, so follow the guidance from the [Restore Data to a Different Server or Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article.

Normally, I'd post relevant snippets here, but the move is lengthy and you don't want to skip any steps. It's better to refer to the source material.

Comment: A lot of my steps are derived from the MS documentation. I was trying to pull out what doesn't apply to my situation and then simplify the steps as much as possible.

Comment: It appears that step 5 is unnecessary, because it is addressed in step 8.

Comment: I'm going to continue refining these steps based on the documentation and my scenario. I'll post the steps I take when I get them sorted out.